# how to find the total sum of particular column using C#?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose In database their is column called INCOME_PER_DAY. I bring data of this column in the gridview .

Now  My question is that I want to find the total sum of the column INCOME_PER_DAY using C# .how to do this?

Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Do this on **server-side** (database).

Return [2 recordsets](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274): one with details and the second one (one row) with SUM(INCOME_PER_DAY).

**or use this query:**

```
SELECT ROW_TYPE = 1, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, INCOME_PER_DAY FROM MYSALES
UNION ALL
SELECT ROW_TYPE = 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, INCOME_PER_DAY = SUM(INCOME_PER_DAY) FROM MYSALES
```

`ROW_TYPE = 1` - detail row
`ROW_TYPE = 2` - summary row

On a page, use, for example, datagrid in the [ItemDataBound](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ItemCreated.aspx) event handler: check ROW_TYPE to apply valid CSS style (detail and summary)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to loop through the column and add up rows line-by-line.